# Apache subdomains on ubuntu server from laptop

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm on my laptop and I want to create subdomains for the server on my network. On my laptop, I modified my hosts file so that I can access my server with the adress `myserver`

If I access `myserver`, I get the default apache server html page saying "it works".

On my server, the default document root is `/var/www/`

I want to create a subdomain for a user such that I would type `user.myserver` and access files at `/home/user/Websites/`

Now, I modified httpd.conf on my server to add:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName *
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName user.localhost
        DocumentRoot "/home/user/Websites/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, my hosts file on my server is modified to:

```
127.0.0.1 user.localhost
```

if I put `user.myserver` on my laptop, my browser says it can't find the server.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to modify hosts file on your server, it's only for server resolving, apache will just listen to what `Host` header it will receive.
2. You need to modify hosts file on your laptop to have `user.myserver` point to the IP of your server.

Comment: @CoachNono: "if I put `user.myserver` on my laptop" -> here as well? And I sanitized my answer from your name as well :)

Comment: if I put user.localhost on my laptop then it would try to access the localserver on my laptop not the server at myserver...

Comment: Ahh, I think now I understand what the problem is :) See edit.

Comment: hmmm. finally, it is still pointing to the content of /var/www/...  Should I delete the first virtual host ?

Comment: Don't delete, just replace `*` in `ServerName` with something else, like `myserver`.

Comment: I've replaced * in ServerName with myserver, localhost or the ip address with success

Comment: Do you have a `NameVirtualHost` directive in your config? If not, you should add one, like `NameVirtualHost *:80`, otherwise it will match on IPs, rather than hostnames and will not do actual host switching.

Comment: by adding this I get this warning when reloading apache : NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21794/discussion-between-favoretti-and-coachnono)